# pagedlist with post method mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, viewbag, pagedlist

I use this `razor` code in order to have pagination in my MVC application. But when I choose one page in the `Pagelist` the get method for search is called, and my `chtml` page refreshes without any data. I think it is because of the get method.Is there a way to have pagination in post method?

```
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.SearchResult, page => Url.Action("Search", new { page = page }), new PagedListRenderOptions { DelimiterBetweenPageNumbers = "|" })
```

Comment: have you debugged the code? Do you know what happens when your Search method is being called? That's the first thing to check.

Comment: When I change the page number, the GET Method called, but I want to call the POST method